# syntax error near unexpected token `)' when using case command

Tags: bash, case

I am parsing option arguments to a bash function, where one of the options allows an optional arguments.

Bash has started to complain about an unexpected token `)', but cannot see clearly what's wrong with the code.

```
bash: /home/hagbard/utils.sh: line 130:
 syntax error near unexpected token `)'
```

The code follows from here

```
-w|--warning)
  case "$2" in
    '/^[0-9]+$/') local -r warn="$2"
    *)            local -r warn="1"
  esac
  shift 2
  ;;
```

Comment: You might visit `shellcheck.net` for syntax checking.

Comment: However, every pattern requires a matching `;;`. The whole case ends with `esac`. I would probably quote case patterns, and I usually use the optional left bracket: `("-w"|"--warning")

Comment: The shift is problematical. If `-w` is (mistakenly) not followed by the expected value, `shift 2` will (a) not shift anything, and (b) throw an error status, which will exit the script if `set -e` is active.

Comment: Tho `-w` is expected to accept an optional argument (`-w` or `-wNUM`).  Am struggling to see the problem with `shift 2`.

Comment: Not seen the rest of the code, so don't know what other options may be present. Normally, options would be dealt with in a loop with `case`. So `myScript -w -x` (no option to -w, separate -x option) would shift off the `-x` as well, and you would not see it. `myscript -w` would refuse to shift off the `-w` by itself and you would loop forever. It does not actually process `-wNUM` -- the pattern does not match that. It references `$2` and processes `-w  NUM`. You might check for `-w9` and `-w  9` and `-w -x` explicitly and shift appropriately, but it is messy.

Comment: We can discuss the `-w` problem by a new question, so we do not get out of topic.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by including `;;` after setting local variable `warn`.

```
  ("-w"|"--warning")
    case "$2" in
      ('/^[0-9]+$/') 
        local -r warn="$2"
        ;;
      (*)            
        local -r warn="1"
    esac
    shift 2
    ;;
```

Comment: The opening parenthesis at the beginning of the pattern is superfluous, but will work

Comment: I do it for others to understand that `case`  uses `patterns` rather than `regular expressions`.

Comment: You should use the shell built-in `getopts` if you don't need --long options, or `/usr/bin/getopt` from `util-linux` (and **only** that version, others are [broken & insecure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getopt#In_Shell)) if you do need them.    Whether you DIY or use getopt/getopts, your first case (with numeric arg) should have `local -r warn="$2" ; shift ;;` and the `shift 2` should be just `shift` - because you always want shift at least one arg, but you only want to shift two args when `-w` has its optional argument.

Comment: I want to use long options.  How is it that still there is not a portable getopt that allows long options.  Where does `getopt` not work?

Comment: Found out that `case` requires patterns rather than regular expressions.

Comment: When I use `-w`, it looks like an empty null character is returned for `$2`, which still requires `shift 2`.

Comment: Does `getopt` always require both a short option and an equivalent long option far every set option.  For instance, can I have a long option without an equivalent short option?